# JSON array and python

Tags: python, json

I am having some problems to parse a JSON object that I get when I GET a URL:

```
[{"id":1,"version":23,"external_id":"2312","url":"https://example.com/432","type":"typeA","date":"2","notes":"notes","title":"title","abstract":"dsadasdas","details":"something","accuracy":0,"reliability":0,"severity":12,"thing":"32132","other":["aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbbbbbbb","cccccccccccccccc","dddddddddddddd","eeeeeeeeee"],"nana":8},{"id":2,"version":23,"external_id":"2312","url":"https://example.com/432","type":"typeA","date":"2","notes":"notes","title":"title","abstract":"dsadasdas","details":"something","accuracy":0,"reliability":0,"severity":12,"thing":"32132","other":["aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbbbbbbb","cccccccccccccccc","dddddddddddddd","eeeeeeeeee"],"nana":8}]
```

Like you can see the JSON start with "[" and ends "]"

I am using this code:

```
import json
import urllib2

data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://someurl/path/to/json'))
print data
```

And I get this:

```
[{u'severity': 12, u'title': u'title', u'url': u'https://example.com/432', u'external_id': u'2312', u'notes': u'notes', u'abstract': u'dsadasdas', u'other': [u'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', u'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb', u'cccccccccccccccc', u'dddddddddddddd', u'eeeeeeeeee'], u'thing': u'32132', u'version': 23, u'nana': 8, u'details': u'something', u'date': u'2', u'reliability': 0, u'type': u'typeA', u'id': 1, u'accuracy': 0}, {u'severity': 12, u'title': u'title', u'url': u'https://example.com/432', u'external_id': u'2312', u'notes': u'notes', u'abstract': u'dsadasdas', u'other': [u'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', u'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb', u'cccccccccccccccc', u'dddddddddddddd', u'eeeeeeeeee'], u'thing': u'32132', u'version': 23, u'nana': 8, u'details': u'something', u'date': u'2', u'reliability': 0, u'type': u'typeA', u'id': 2, u'accuracy': 0}]
```

If the JSON is too large I don't get the full info.

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: whats wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `[]` in json. It simply means a list. To pretty print your json try this:

```
import json
import urllib2

data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://someurl/path/to/json'))
print json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

To find particular object just do this:

```
obj = next((obj for obj in data if obj["id"] == 2), None)
```

Comment: Thank you! I am so newbie using JSON. How must do if I want to access to the field "details" of the object that has the id "2"?? Thank you again!

Comment: @martineau is right there is a error with this code and it does not work

Comment: Sorry, forgot parentheses when adding None

Comment: Alberto: note that the expression return the first object in the list that has an id of "2", however, general speaking, there could be more than one.